SVG sprite in CSS
I can't use the SVG using SVG sprite
here's the css,
strong {
    font-weight: inherit;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;

        width: 100%;
        height: 2rem;
        // background-image: url(../../SVGs/strong-line.svg);
        background-image: url("../sprite.svg#strong-line");

        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        bottom: -0.2rem;
        left: 0;
    }
}

here's the SVG sprite which contains 15 SVGs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
<symbol id="stay-updated"><path fill="#033B30" d="M68.754 54.52c0-4.768-3.404-8.742-7.9-9.661V26.503C60.855 11.873 48.983 0 34.378 0S7.899 11.873 7.899 26.503v18.356C3.403 45.778 0 49.752 0 54.52c0 5.415 4.421 9.836 9.86 9.836h49.033c5.44 0 9.86-4.421 9.86-9.836M34.377 77c5.961 0 11.103-3.676 13.239-8.917H21.138C23.274 73.324 28.415 77 34.377 77"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="strong-line"><path stroke="#F5D31F" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="8" d="m4 25 9.909-14.565c3.723-5.473 11.994-4.792 14.772 1.216v0c2.389 5.166 9.075 6.58 13.35 2.823l5.511-4.84a13.995 13.995 0 0 1 17.074-1.082l5.417 3.66a15 15 0 0 0 15.974.52l7.291-4.266a15 15 0 0 1 18.387 2.55l.788.82c5.493 5.712 14.482 6.166 20.522 1.036l1.951-1.656c5.838-4.959 14.474-4.722 20.031.549l2.847 2.699c5.998 5.688 15.656 4.968 20.883-1.436v0c4.75-5.818 13.335-6.923 19.313-2.376l5.172 3.933c4.858 3.694 11.904 1.659 14.042-4.058v0c2.089-5.58 8.886-7.686 13.763-4.262L247 17.5"/>
</symbol>
</svg>

it works well when I use the single SVG like this background-image: url(../../SVGs/strong-line.svg);  other than that it doesn't show anything just an empty box with the specified height and width

background-image cannot point to a symbol element. Only an SVG  element can refer to a symbol element.

You can also refactor your SVG to work with fragment identifiers. See also: "How do I use the icon from the .svg sprite directly in the CSS/SCSS?"
